# BaseApplLayer.h file not found

Tags: omnet++, veins

I am trying to build a veins application. But i am getting the following error:

veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/VADDBaseWaveApplLayer.h:25:10: fatal error: 'BaseApplLayer.h' file not found

The complete line in VADDBaseWaveApplLayer.h is:
 #include "veins/base/modules/BaseApplLayer.h"

However, the file is there, in the  correct directory.

Im not sure how to correct this. Thank you

Comment: Are you sure about this? If I recall correctly, clang++ outputs verbatim what file it was trying to find. It should have reported `fatal error: 'veins/base/modules/BaseApplLayer.h' file not found`.

Comment: Hi, thats possible, i might have added the full file name when trying to fix the issue.